# Are listeners a good solution for this, and how are they implemented?

Tags: java, android, architecture, listener, handler

In my Android project, I've got a singleton class that retrieves data from an external source every second. When data is retrieved, it should inform some data display objects that there is new data available so that they can update themselves.

I believe that the best way to implement this is to let the data displayers implement some listening interface and then register with the data retriever singleton.

Is this a good solution? How is this problem normally solved? Are there any ready classes/frameworks for this that I should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to implement the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) via [`Observer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html) interface and [`Observable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) class. For example:

```
import java.util.Observable;

public class DataModel extends Observable
{
    public void retrieveData()
    {
        // ...

        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(); // or notifyObservers(someData);
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.Observer;

public class ViewClass implements Observer
{
    @Override
    public void update(Observable observable, Object data)
    {
        // update the view
    }
}
```

You need to register the observers like this:

```
DataModel dm = ...;
dm.addObserver(viewClass1);
dm.addObserver(viewClass2);
dm.addObserver(viewClass3);
```

Comment: You should properly not use this classes as they have a number of drawbacks. ```Observable``` is a class and as there is no multiple inheritance  in java this might be a no go. Just implement both the Observable and the Observer yourself!

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a Callback. If new data is available the other Classes which implement the Callback will be informed automatically.

Here is a nice description of [Callbacks](http://www.javaworld.com/javatips/jw-javatip10.html).

Answer (score 2):

Yes looks like a classic usecase for the observer pattern. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern